# How to parse a complex string using jQuery Tablesorter plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a table like this I'd like to sort : 
**| Name    | Case     |** 
| John    | X-123/08 P| 
| Bob     | X-123/09  | 
| Dylan   | X-45/10   |

I want to sort the Case colum by case's year then case's number knowing that the format is always "X-(1 to 4 digits for case's number)/(case's year on 2 digits) (sometimes some text)". It's possible that after the year's case I have some text but it shoud be ignored for sorting.

I am using tablesorter jQuery's plugin and I am struggling to add a custom parser for this.

Thanks for your help !

EDIT : Here's what I'm trying to do :

```
jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({ 
                // set a unique id 
                id: 'case', 
                is: function(s) { 
                    return false; 
                }, 
                format: function(s) { 
                    // format your data for normalization 
                    return s.replace(/^X-\d{1,4}\/(\d{2}).*$/, '$1') + ('000' + s.replace(/^X-(\d{1,4})\/\d{2}.*$/, '$1')).substr(-4);
                }, 
                // set type, either numeric or text 
                type: 'text'
            });
```

It's working great until I encounter a case with 2 digits which is then ranked greater than a 3 digits one and I don't understand why ...
"X-458/09 P" is sorted smaller than "X-48/09" . I'll try some debug to see what really happens.

EDIT 2 : Also tried the second answer :

```
jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({ 
                // set a unique id 
                id: 'case', 
                is: function(s) { 
                    return false; 
                }, 
                format: function(s) { 
                    var m = s.match(/X\-(\d+)\/(\d{2}).*$/);
                    var affaire = m[1];
                    var year = m[2];
                    return year + '000' + affaire;
                }, 
                // set type, either numeric or text 
                type: 'text'
            });
```

The result seems to be the same as the first one... I really can't understand why it sucks. Why tablesorter thinks that 488 000 10 is smaller than 49 000 10 ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'case', 
    is: function(s) { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        // format your data for normalization 
        return s.replace(/^X-\d{1,4}\/(\d{2}).*$/, '$1') + ('000' + s.replace(/^X-(\d{1,4})\/\d{2}.*$/, '$1')).slice(-4);
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'text'
});
```

EDIT:

Maybe you already tried something like this with `type: 'numeric'`; I'm not sure, but this may fail because `parseInt('09') === 0`.

EDIT 2:

Changed to reflect sorting by year, then case number.

Comment: I already tried that but it doesn't seem to work =( I tried both numeric and text. I added something in description of the question, maybe that's the cause..

Comment: Sometimes some text, eh? :) Try adding `.*` before the `$` at the end? Does that work at all?

Comment: Yep some text like that : "X-123/07 PRU" or "X-54/11 P(C)" It's usually just a few letters and they shouldn't be considered for sorting process. I tried with .* but still no chance.

Comment: Ok, just to be sure: you did add `$("table").tablesorter({ headers: { 1: { sorter:'case' } } });` or something, right? Because "X-54/11 P(C)".replace(/^X-\d{1,4}\/(\d{2}).*$/, '$1') returns "11" in my console... Are you sure the format function is called? Maybe add some debugging code in there, or just `alert(s); alert(s.replace(/^X-\d{1,4}\/(\d{2}).*$/, '$1'));`?

Comment: Parser is called, I already did some debug to check that. The year is well returned indeed when I try an alert(...) but what I want is to sort by year then by case's number (inside a year) =/

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't get that... I changed the regexp to include the case number. However, in this case 54 will be greater than 123, so if you want to eliminate that as well, you will have to use more than one regexp (I think). I included an example in the comment underneath (padding with zeroes). EDIT: or, use .match() instead of .replace() to get the case and year like @Nick Craver did, then add them together with the zeroes in between.

Comment: We're almost there but not exactly. I don't really understand your commented expression and this is the one I need to use because I don't want 54 to be greater than 123. I tried it and it sorts my list pretty well except for the 2 digits cases which are greater than 3 digits (for instance X-228/10 smaller than X-25/10). Could you detail more precisely what you're trying to do ?

Comment: Well, I want the string to be the last 4 characters of '000' + the case number. That way (I think) it should be ordered in the correct, um, order. Also, I'm pretty sure this "should work". Can you show me some of your code? I'll also update the answer.

Comment: I vote up for your answer because it helped me a lot to get the successful one ! Thx :)

Comment: Hmm... how about if you use `slice` instead of `substr`? (and also, thanks :) but I would still like this to be the best answer ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to get the 2 values you're after, for example:

```
var columnVal = "X-123/08";
var m = columnVal.match(/X\-(\d+)\/(\d{2})$/);
var case = m[1];
var year = m[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple things this one seems to work perfectly well :

```
jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({ 
                // set a unique id 
                id: 'case', 
                is: function(s) { 
                    return false; 
                }, 
                format: function(s) { 
                    var m = s.match(/X\-(\d+)\/(\d{2}).*$/);
                    var caseVar = '000' + m[1];
                    var size = caseVar.length;
                    caseVar= caseVar.substr(size-4, 4);
                    var year = m[2];
                    return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat(year + caseVar);
                }, 
                // set type, either numeric or text 
                type: 'numeric'
            });
```

I did some research and it appears that the substr function with a negative value doesn't work on all browser (I'm using IE because my application must be IE compliant). I think that's the cause of my previous problems and that's why Spiny's solution wasn't working for me.

Thanks anyway to all of you for your precious help !